# ¿Como colocar imagen destacada en post de wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, post, wordpress-theme, wordpress-imagenes

Uso mi plantilla Uncode la cuál me permite poner la opción de colocar mi imagen destacada al inicio del post, sin embargo, en mis entradas solamente coloca la imagen cuando la imagen es grande, si la imagen es "pequeña" menos de 1500 de ancho (al parecer) no la coloca. Adjunto imágenes de 2 post que ambas contienen imagen destacada
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: eso tiene que ver más por cómo está desarrollada tu plantilla, trata de ver si puedes intervenir el evento que hace escribir esa imagen con algún webhook en wordpress, pero si nos queremos ver más radicales, trata de ubicar el archivo .php que hace escribir esa imagen y cambia la condición

Comment: Alguna idea de donde pueda estar la función que coloca la imagen? he checado el archivo single.php sin embargo no veo ninguna linea de código que maneje tamaños de imagen o algo similar

Comment: abre un chat para ayudarte mejor

Comment: No puedo crear salas de chat, no me aparece el botón de crear sala

Comment: Alguien puede apoyar con alguna idea?